# Highlight a word based on search pattern in a string content

Tags: java, regex

i am trying to write a sample java program using regular expression which highlights a word in a string content based on given pattern. 
i tried following code. but no luck

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(test).*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
String replaceAll = pattern.matcher(str).replaceAll("<span>$1</span>");
```

Ex 1:

```
input content : i am testing a program
input pattern : test*
expected : i am <span>testing<span> a program
```

Ex 2 :

```
input content : i am testing a program
input pattern : test
expected : i am <span>test<span>ing a program
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace the `*` with `\w*` in the input pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
    String input = "i am testing a program";
    System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(?i)test\\S*", "<span>$0</span>"));
    // -> i am <span>testing</span> a program
    System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(?i)test", "<span>$0</span>"));
    // -> i am <span>test</span>ing a program
```

`(?i)` means CASE_INSENSITIVE.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help.

Comment: can you help with same pattern in java  script ? Thanks.

Comment: var input = "i am testing a programing";
var query = new RegExp("(program[a-z]+)", "gim");
alert(input.replace(query, "<span>$1</span>"));   working.. thanks

Comment: Thank you for the solution!

Comment: Hi @saka1029,  This code is not working in Android API 23 and lesser. Any suggestions??